Expo Router freezes screen when using gestures to dismiss a stack screen after dismissing a modal
I've submitted an issue to Expo for this, but I was wondering if anyone might have a good workaround for now.
Basically, if I have tabs -> a stack screen -> a child stack screen -> a modal, and I pull the modal to dismiss it followed by pulling from the left to go back a screen, there's a _UIParallaxDimmingView that gets stuck hanging over the stack disabling inputs from the user.
I'd rather not disable gestures and the modal is in a shared folder because it's used across stacks.
Thanks!

Facing similar issue , managed to find a solution/workaround ?

@JimmyObonyoAbor, I'm afraid not.  We disabled one of the gestures.  Here's an open issue with expo:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/29942
